# Do any branches of graph theory consider abstraction?

Tags: graph, graph-theory, owl, ontology

By abstraction I mean treating a complex structure as a simpler structure: in this case, treating a graph as a node.

Do any branches of graph theory (or web ontology engineering) include a construct which can incorporate a graph into another graph as a node?

A couple of use cases for this would be expressing beliefs in a mind map (JOHN ---->  BELIEVES ----> [another graph]), or expressing confidence in web ontology languages.

As far as I know, in OWL, we have to "fake" representing a subgraph (triple) by connecting a starting node separately to a node which represents the triple, then connecting this with three (subject, relationship, object) nodes.

Thanks
Louise

Comment: See https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-primer/#reification

Comment: Thanks Dan. However, this is exactly what I've described in my fourth paragraph. Reification in OWL only allows us to reify individual statements, not whole graphs.